# protege SOVA plugin does not work

Tags: java, protege

I installed SOVA plugging (org.pg.eti.kask.ont.pluginSova-0.8.5.jar) for Protege-5.0.0-beta-21. I'm using java version "1.8.0_72". I'm getting the following exception when I click "PG ETI SOVA- Visualization" tab. The tab: "PG ETI SOVA -Hierarchy Tree Vis" works just fine. If someone could explain the exception that would be helpful.

Thanks for the help.

```
Uncaught Exception in thread 'AWT-EventQueue-0' 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClass.getSuperClasses
(Lorg/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLOntology;)Ljava/util/Set;
at org.pg.eti.kask.sova.graph.OWLtoGraphConverter.insertBaseClasses(OWLtoGraphConverter.java:177) ~[na:na]
at org.pg.eti.kask.sova.graph.OWLtoGraphConverter.OWLtoGraph(OWLtoGraphConverter.java:839) ~[na:na]
at org.pg.eti.kask.sova.visualization.OVDisplay.generateGraphFromOWl(OVDisplay.java:237) ~[na:na]
at org.pg.eti.kask.ont.pluginSova.SovaVisualization.initialiseOWLView(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.protege.editor.owl.ui.view.AbstractOWLViewComponent.initialise(AbstractOWLViewComponent.java:46) ~[na:na]
at org.protege.editor.core.ui.view.View.createContent(View.java:423) ~[na:na]
at org.protege.editor.core.ui.view.View.createUI(View.java:203) ~[na:na]
at org.protege.editor.core.ui.view.View$1.hierarchyChanged(View.java:133) ~[na:na]
at java.awt.Component.processHierarchyEvent(Component.java:6692) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6311) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Component.createHierarchyEvents(Component.java:5541) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1443) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1439) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1439) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1439) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1439) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1439) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1622) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1654) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1606) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at javax.swing.JComponent.setVisible(JComponent.java:2644) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.fireStateChanged(JTabbedPane.java:394) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at javax.swing.JTabbedPane$ModelListener.stateChanged(JTabbedPane.java:270) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at javax.swing.DefaultSingleSelectionModel.fireStateChanged(DefaultSingleSelectionModel.java:132) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at javax.swing.DefaultSingleSelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(DefaultSingleSelectionModel.java:67) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndexImpl(JTabbedPane.java:616) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(JTabbedPane.java:591) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:3647) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:280) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:279) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6522) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4530) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201) [na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116) [na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105) [na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93) [na:1.8.0_40]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82) [na:1.8.0_40]
2
```

Comment: Probably version problem of the different jar you are using

Answer (score 0):

The exception you're seeing means that the plugin needs to be updated to work with OWLAPI 4. Protege beta 18 and newer use OWLAPI 4.